# Using jquery with regex for validaton

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, jquery-validate

I am having a really hard time using Regex with the jquery validate plugin. My code is:

```
jQuery.validator.methods.nameCheck  = function(value) {
  return  /^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\,\.\- ][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/i.test(value);
};

jQuery.validator.methods.emailCheck  = function(value) {
      return  /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/i.test(value);
};

jQuery.validator.methods.AddressRegex  = function(value) {
      return    /^[a-zA-Z0-9][#&-\'\,\.]*$/i.test(value);
};

jQuery.validator.methods.lettersonly = function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z]*$/i.test(value);
}; 

jQuery.validator.methods.PasswordRegex = function(value) {
      return /^[a-zA-Z0-9\,!#$%^&*()_-+\.]+$/i.test(value);
};
```

The first two work, but even lettersonly, which seems simple enough, isn't doing what it is supposed to do. They are being called properly further down the form.

Comment: This is a handy tool I use to check my regex. Might help with this or in the future when you are working with regex. [http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm)

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of alphanumeric that as i use it if you want just alpha remove the 0-9

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) { 
    return  this.optional(element) || value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/);
}, "This field may only contain alpha numeric characters.");
```

that should get you started just duplicate and adjust using your regex's

ohh and I would just use validate's email rather than build your own

Comment: I dont think my boss "trusts" jquerys validate, so I threw both in for good measure. Im getting there, thank you!

Comment: well whatever you want to do keep in mind that you should always do a double check server side

Comment: so to use this would you just do the following?

    $('#myForm').validate({
      rules: {
       "myInput": {
    alphanumeric: true,
        ...,
 ...,
       }

Comment: @JeffSilva yes or you could just add it as a class